# Where the const reduce performance rather than optimizing it?

Tags: c, optimization, constants, compiler-optimization

Please take a look at following code snippet

```
#define HF_ND_SZ sizeof(struct huffman_node)
#define TSIZE_MAX 256

struct huffman_node * build_decomp_huffman_tree(uint64_t *table, int size) {
    static struct huffman_node huffman_node_list2[TSIZE_MAX * 3];
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int k = TSIZE_MAX * 2; // this is the case point 1
    //...//
    for (i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        huffman_node_list2[k + i] = huffman_node_list2[i + 1]; // point 2
        huffman_node_list2[TSIZE_MAX + i].right = &huffman_node_list2[k+ i];
    // ... //
    }
    return &huffman_node_list2[size - 1];
}
```

For simplicity I reduced the code and point out the locations where I want to highlight,also do not think algorithm and structure too deeply.

What I want to is that if we define **point 1** as `const int k = TSIZE_MAX * 2;`,then is there any optimization happens at **point 2 or 3** where assignment happens to contiguous data(array) `huffman_node_list2[k + i] = huffman_node_list2[i + 1];` ?

(Please bear with and correct my assumption if it is wrong,I thought when we declare `const` in local or global scope it's being created as an immutable memory allocation, if we use that **immutable memory** and carried out **math operation** as in **point 2 or 3**(`[k + i]`) in a loop structure ,during runtime program has to **load** immutable memory every iteration of the loop and store the result in temporary memory location,what if happend if that immutable memory has large chunk,hope you can grab my idea,Am I correct?)

Comment: Is there an actual problem, or are you just asking in order to learn? `const` for an entity means that the compiler will not allow code that modifies it, but it could well be stored in modifiable memory. Even when it is stored in nonmodifiable memory (from the point of view of the process - the difference is only that the kernel will have made that memory page read-only), it does not need to first be copied somewhere else, so I see no reason for `const` to make things slower. Modifiable memory too is loaded into registers for fast handling.

Comment: @ArndtJonasson thanks you that's what I am asking, you straight to the point ` Modifiable memory too is loaded into registers for fast handling`  as you said, therefore is n't it wise to use `non-const` rather than `const` declaration? Is `const data` also loaded to register `faster than non-const`?

Comment: The purpose of `const` isn't to make code faster, it's to make code more correct. When you mark something `const`, you're asking the compiler to tell you (via an error) if/when you try to modify it.

Comment: `const` doesn't necessarily create a memory location at all, unless you take its address. More probably `huffman_node_list2[k + i] = huffman_node_list2[i + 1]` gets compiled as `huffman_node_list2[TSIZE_MAX * 2 + i] = huffman_node_list2[i + 1]`, where not only is `TSIZE_MAX * 2` evaluated at compile time but so is `huffman_node_list2+TSIZE_MAX*2` if you see what I mean.

Comment: As for performance, unfortunately it's not always true that something marked const can't be modified (because of `const_cast`) so compiler has to rely on its own analysis of the code to determine if something changes or not. It will optimize the code based on its analysis alone, there's nothing you can do about that.

Comment: @SirGuy It's UB to modify a variable declared `const`, so no, it's always true a variable marked `const` can't be modified. `const_cast` is only legal on stuff like const reference

Comment: @SirGuy oh! `const` acting like a flag or as an inspector kind of thing? rather than creating `immutable` memory alloc?  thank you, and sorry for my misunderstanding, I was with a confusion that `const` things stored in to `Read Only Memory` area kind of thing.

Comment: @EJP thank you got it.yeah `TSIZE_MAX * 2` evaluated at compile time... therefore  `k` just a const reference kind of thing isn't it?I don't know too much of interanls!!!

Comment: You can have a modifiable variable in one function, and then call another function with it, the second function having its argument declared as pointer to const, and then the second function is not allowed to modify the variable through the pointer, although it is modifiable. It can do so anyway by casting to a pointer type without const, but that will give a warning from the compiler. Very occasionally, doing that is the short-term solution to a problem, but don't design programs that way.

Comment: @EJP your comment would make for a decent answer... I’d upvote it as such.

Comment: @ArndtJonasson got your point, thank you very much.

Comment: Also, you *must* decide whether you're asking about **C** or **C++** as the very meaning of `const` is vastly different between the 2!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I am using this with `C` , can you briefly tell me what is the major factor behind `const` regarding compiler optimization differ between `C` and `C++`?

Comment: @PasserBy Modifying a const after casting the const away is only undefined behavior if the object referenced is indeed const (i.e., could reside in non-modifiable memory). For example, passing the address of a modifiable object to a function as a pointer to const just because I thought the function should have no business modifying it and then modifying it anyway in the function is not UB. E.g. `int i=0; void incr(const int *ip){ ++(*(int *)ip); } void call(){ incr(&i); }` is fine.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider I did mention that :)? `int i = 0;` isn't a variable declared const, and modifying it is fine.

Comment: @PasserBy I see. Yes, you mentioned that.

Answer (score 1):

Using Visual C, I compiled both versions of your code : with `const int k` and without `const`. The flag `/FA` produces code machine in a `.asm` file readable by (some) human. No optimization flags were used.

The result is : there's no optimization, no difference. The machine code produced is strictly the same :

```
; Listing generated by Microsoft (R) Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.24231.0 

    TITLE   opt_const.c
    .686P
    .XMM
    include listing.inc
    .model  flat

INCLUDELIB LIBCMT
INCLUDELIB OLDNAMES

PUBLIC  _main
_BSS    SEGMENT
?huffman_node_list2@?1??main@@9@9 DB 01fd4H DUP (?) ; `main'::`2'::huffman_node_list2
_BSS    ENDS
; Function compile flags: /Odtp
; File c:\joël\tests\opt_const.c
_TEXT   SEGMENT
_j$ = -16                       ; size = 4
_size$ = -12                        ; size = 4
_k$ = -8                        ; size = 4
_i$ = -4                        ; size = 4
_argc$ = 8                      ; size = 4
_argv$ = 12                     ; size = 4
_main   PROC

; 10   : {

    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, 16                 ; 00000010H
    push    esi
    push    edi

; 11   :     static struct huffman_node huffman_node_list2[TSIZE_MAX * 3];
; 12   :     int i = 0, j = 0, size = 17;

    mov DWORD PTR _i$[ebp], 0
    mov DWORD PTR _j$[ebp], 0
    mov DWORD PTR _size$[ebp], 17       ; 00000011H

; 13   :     int k = TSIZE_MAX * 2; // this is the case point 1

    mov DWORD PTR _k$[ebp], 194         ; 000000c2H

; 14   :     //...//
; 15   :     for (i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {

    mov DWORD PTR _i$[ebp], 0
    jmp SHORT $LN4@main
$LN2@main:
    mov eax, DWORD PTR _i$[ebp]
    add eax, 1
    mov DWORD PTR _i$[ebp], eax
$LN4@main:
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR _size$[ebp]
    sub ecx, 1
    cmp DWORD PTR _i$[ebp], ecx
    jge SHORT $LN3@main

; 16   :         huffman_node_list2[k + i] = huffman_node_list2[i + 1]; // point 2

    mov edx, DWORD PTR _i$[ebp]
    add edx, 1
    imul    esi, edx, 28
    add esi, OFFSET ?huffman_node_list2@?1??main@@9@9
    mov eax, DWORD PTR _k$[ebp]
    add eax, DWORD PTR _i$[ebp]
    imul    edi, eax, 28
    add edi, OFFSET ?huffman_node_list2@?1??main@@9@9
    mov ecx, 7
    rep movsd

; 17   :         huffman_node_list2[TSIZE_MAX + i].right = &huffman_node_list2[k+ i];

    mov ecx, DWORD PTR _k$[ebp]
    add ecx, DWORD PTR _i$[ebp]
    imul    edx, ecx, 28
    add edx, OFFSET ?huffman_node_list2@?1??main@@9@9
    mov eax, DWORD PTR _i$[ebp]
    add eax, 97                 ; 00000061H
    imul    ecx, eax, 28
    mov DWORD PTR ?huffman_node_list2@?1??main@@9@9[ecx], edx

; 18   :     // ... //
; 19   :     }

    jmp SHORT $LN2@main
$LN3@main:

; 20   :     return 0;

    xor eax, eax

; 21   : }

    pop edi
    pop esi
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret 0
_main   ENDP
_TEXT   ENDS
END
```

EDIT : I did the same test with gcc, -O3 optimization flags.
And... same result : the generated assembler code is again stricly the same with and without the `const` keyword.

```
        .file       "opt_const.c"
        .section    .text.unlikely,"ax",@progbits
.LCOLDB0:
        .section    .text.startup,"ax",@progbits
.LHOTB0:
        .p2align 4,,15
        .globl      main
        .type       main, @function
main:
.LFB23:
        .cfi_startproc
        movl        $huffman_node_list2.2488+16384, %eax
        .p2align 4,,10
        .p2align 3
.L2:
        movq        -16352(%rax), %rdx
        movq        %rax, -8192(%rax)
        addq        $32, %rax
        movq        %rdx, -32(%rax)
        movq        -16376(%rax), %rdx
        movq        %rdx, -24(%rax)
        movq        -16368(%rax), %rdx
        movq        %rdx, -16(%rax)
        movq        -16360(%rax), %rdx
        movq        %rdx, -8(%rax)
        cmpq        $huffman_node_list2.2488+17088, %rax
        jne .L2
        xorl        %eax, %eax
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE23:
        .size       main, .-main
        .section    .text.unlikely
.LCOLDE0:
        .section    .text.startup
.LHOTE0:
        .local      huffman_node_list2.2488
        .comm       huffman_node_list2.2488,24576,32
        .ident      "GCC: (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 5.4.0 20160609"
        .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Comment: Visual C is a bad excuse for a C compiler to my mind but still this does not make this answer bad. But which optimizations were activated, this might be more important in the analysis.

Comment: Was this assembly produced with optimisation turned on?

Comment: Optimization was turned on for GCC test only.

Answer (score 1):

`const` *can* be slower if the compiler puts it in the read only .text section far enough away that causes a cache miss.

This can happen with global `const`s or when the compiler hoists it out of a function rather than having to build it with instructions (a fairly common optimization for structs or arrays)  This can reduce code size if multiple functions use the same constant, but also increases the distance from the code and thus the likeliness to cause a miss.

Since you aren't using any aggregate types, there should be no difference with a decent optimizing compiler.

There is a good article on how different data gets laid out [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-layout-of-c-program/)

Answer (score 0):

`const` doesn't necessarily create a memory location at all, unless you take its address. They can just disappear into the instruction stream as immediate-mode constants, or be added into addresses at compile or link time.

For example, `huffman_node_list2[k + i] = huffman_node_list2[i + 1]` is almost certainly compiled as `huffman_node_list2[TSIZE_MAX * 2 + i] = huffman_node_list2[i + 1]`, where not only is `TSIZE_MAX * 2` evaluated at compile time but `huffman_node_list2+TSIZE_MAX*2` is evaluated at link time.